# Finding the probability of the sample standard deviation using Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

The maximum wind speed on any given day in Dublin is modelled as
Normally distributed with mean 10 knots and standard deviation 2 knots.

(a) Explain potential deficiencies of using the Normal distribution to model
wind speeds.

(b) In a 5 day working week what is the probability that at least 2 of the
days have maximum wind speed of more than 9 knots, using the
Normal distribution?

(c) In a 7 day week, what is the probability that the sample standard
deviation is less than 2.5 knots, using the Normal distribution?

I have solved the a) and b) part of the questions however I am a bit confused for the c) part. If anyone can help me over how to solve this.

Comment: The statistic $\left(n - 1\right)S^{2}/\sigma^{2}$ will be Chi-squared distributed with $n - 1$ degrees of freedom, where $S^{2}$ is the sample variance, $n$ is the sample size and $\sigma$ is the population standard deviation.

Comment: But I have to find it using the normal distribution.

Comment: I took it to mean to use the normal distribution in the sense of 'applying the normal assumption on wind speeds'. Either way, the Chi-squared distribution can be derived from the normal distribution I so don't see why it can't be used.